# How can I specify the current schema for sql server in a jboss data source url?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jboss7.x

I've got some SQL queries like this

```
select user_id from 
table_user where lower(email_address)=? and password=?
```

The schema for the application was recently updated but I don't really want to update every SQL query in the application. Is there a way to specify the current Schema from the JBOSS connection end?

Old connection: `jdbc:sqlserver://myserver:1433;DatabaseName=db`
Tried: `jdbc:sqlserver://myserver:1433;DatabaseName=db;currentSchema=abc`

I tried using `currentSchema` but that didn't help, I get a missing object exception when I run the queries (since I assume these are looking under dbo). Is there any way around updating the queries since I know that all the queries will run on schema `abc`?

Comment: You should create two datasources and use the required datasource depending up on scenario. It's not a standard/recommended practice to change the Connection information at the time of SQL query execution.

Comment: @Phani I would really only need 1 datasource since this application will always use that schema. Based on the driver properties though, there doesn't seem to be a way to specify the schema through the connection string.

Comment: If that's the case, then DBA will configure a user and associate to schema and when you use those credentials, then it will refer to the right schema.That's the standard/recommended approach as it doesn't make sense to hard code schema names in SQL.

Comment: @Phani I looked into this a bit more and this seems like a viable option. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/07/sql-server-importance-of-database-schemas-in-sql-server/. Care to add it as an answer for others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[These are the available connection properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988.aspx) for Microsoft JDBC 4.0 driver. I don't see `currentSchema` in this list, and haven't seen any driver that allows you to specify a particular schema in the connection string.

Since you don't want to update SQL with the schema, you could create [synonyms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx) in default (dbo) schema for each object. For example:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
-- create test schema
CREATE SCHEMA test AUTHORIZATION dbo;
GO

-- create table in test schema
CREATE TABLE test.tablename (columnname int null);

-- select from tablename in default schema will fail
SELECT * FROM tablename;
GO

-- create synonym mapping test.tablename to dbo.tablename
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[tablename] FOR [server].[tempdb].[test].[tablename]

-- -- select from tablename synonym will succeed
SELECT * FROM tablename;

-- cleanup
DROP SYNONYM [dbo].[tablename];
DROP TABLE [test].[tablename];
DROP SCHEMA [test];
```

You can use the below code to generate `CREATE SYNONYM` statements for user objects. If you use it, you'll need to update variable values and review statements before executing. No warranty express or implied :)

```
-- generate create synonym statements for user objects
DECLARE @FromSchema SYSNAME = 'abc',
        @ToSchema SYSNAME = 'dbo',
        @ServerName SYSNAME = 'server',
        @DatabaseName SYSNAME = 'database';

SELECT  'CREATE SYNONYM ' + QUOTENAME(@ToSchema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name) +
        ' FOR ' + QUOTENAME(@ServerName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) +
        '.' + QUOTENAME(@FromSchema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'
FROM    sys.objects
WHERE   is_ms_shipped = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and suggestion. This is an interesting approach but I will likely run into issues once other schemas are added and I have conflicting object names. Since there is no driver that allows you to specify the schema, I will settle with updating the SQL. Thanks though.

Comment: @Rondel Updating the SQL would be my first choice. If you get in the habit of always writing `schema`.`object` it's not too cumbersome.