# Create View in specified MSSQL-Schema

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, view, database-schema

I'm using an Apache Tomcat 7.0.41 and need to generate a View on a SQL Server 2012 with the official "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"-Driver.
Unfortunately there seems to be a problem with selecting the Schema. I've tried several ways to accomplish it, yet it fails every time.

Strangely a regular creation of a table doesn't cause any troubles:

```
CREATE TABLE Defschem.dbo.Formate (
[FormatID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[Info] [varchar](50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
[FVal] [float] NOT NULL)
```

Trying to do the View the same way.
(fyi: The Statement itself and the the Tablenames are both separated `final Strings`, which can be changed separately)
:

```
Create View Defschem.dbo.EtiFormatview as 
SELECT 
...
 FROM Defschem.dbo.Formate  
...
```

fails with the error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 'CREATE/ALTER VIEW'
>   does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object
>   name.
>   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)

Leaving the Database name completely puts the created View in the "master"-Database which is not exactly what I wanted.

The error is common and http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-166.aspx suggests:

> To avoid this error, remove the database name when creating a view:
>   [...] If you need to create a view on another database, change your
>   database first then create the view without the database name:

```
USE Northwind
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[CustomerCountries]
AS
SELECT DISTINCT [Country]
FROM [dbo].[Customers]
GO
```

I've started the whole SQL-Command with:

```
"USE " + DATABASENAME + '\n' + "GO " + '\n';
```

to:

```
USE Defschem
GO 
Create View Defschem.dbo.EtiFormatview as 
    SELECT 
    ...
     FROM Defschem.dbo.Formate  
    ...
```

It gets the error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near
>   'GO'.

I'm not sure if my '\n's aren't beautiful enough for the SQL-Server... I couldn't figure out why the Syntax should be incorrect, so I've inserted the whole SQL into the SQL-Management Studio... AND IT WORKED!

I have difficulties to understand why one and the same command works in the Studio but not if executed with Java?
The command is straight forward (I'm using regular Statements instead of Prepared ones because I don't insert any values and all my Strings are final):

```
stat = c.createStatement();
stat.executeUpdate(Info.getUsage()+VIEW);
c.commit();
```

The official documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx - See the "Examples" section) refers to cases in which a semicolon is used after the GO SCHEMA. 
But a change to:

```
"USE " + DATABASENAME + ";\n" + "GO " + '\n';
```

gives me exactly the same error. Leaving the '\n's away has no effect either.

It appears someone faced a similar issue a while ago:
[How can I specify the current schema for sql server in a jboss data source url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820696/how-can-i-specify-the-current-schema-for-sql-server-in-a-jboss-data-source-url)

I haven't worked with Synonyms before and I don't think that's the right approach for my problem. Is there a more elegant solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statements like `USE` can technically be used in JDBC. However you cannot use `GO`, as that is not part of the SQL Server T-SQL syntax; it is actually part of SQL Server Management Studio and a number of scripting tools for SQL Server.

However direct use of commands that influence the state of the connection (including others like for transactions (start, commit rollback)) are strongly discouraged by JDBC:

> **Note**: When configuring a `Connection`, JDBC applications should use the appropriate Connection method such as `setAutoCommit` or `setTransactionIsolation`. Applications should not invoke SQL commands directly to change the connection's configuration when there is a JDBC method available. *(from [`java.sql.Connection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html))*

If you want to switch databases, you can use [`Connection.setCatalog()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setCatalog-java.lang.String-). This way the connection knows it is now connected to a different catalog. If you do this with `USE` instead, the driver might still think it is connected to the initial database and do the wrong things (eg caching metadata for the wrong database, etc).

The other option of course is described in [the answer by Donal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26226669/466862): connect directly to the right database.

Comment: You are right - I had never dealt with the `USE` and `GO` command before (and would be happy not to use it again). Yet, the Answer by @Donai did not work for me, but with the Catalog-Setting it proceeded as it should.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the database name as part of the connection string. This means you then do not need a `USE` statement - because the database in your connection string is your current database.

For example:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://servername:1433;databaseName=TheActualDatabaseName;user=UserName;password=*****;";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

Once connected to the database, you do not need to use it in your SQL. You do not need to use the schema name either - dbo is the default schema in SQL Server and you can leave it out.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Formate (
[FormatID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[Info] [varchar](50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
[FVal] [float] NOT NULL)
)
```

Comment: It seems the SQL-Server is causing troubles with Schema/DB-Options, it did not work...